# Adding Chinese support for Postgres FTS on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have installed and added [`zhparser`](https://howardlee.cloud/blog/129/) locally which improves the FTS for Chinese characters - we are using `pg_search` gem for this too. Now issue is that I want to install `zhparser` and use that on the Postgres add-on in Heroku, but found out that it can't be done outside of the supported add-ons/buildpacks.

I'm in a bind now. Does anyone here know how I can add Chinese support for FTS on Heroku's Postgres? Could it be using a different extension or add-on that I'm not aware?

Thanks!